# Irregular binning p2 python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scatter-plot, binning

I have one small follow up question regarding binning in python pandas.

I have a data-frame like the following:

```
df = 
 variable    test_score
-1           52.0
 1           53.0
 4           54.0
 6           64.0
 6           64.0
-6           64.0
 5           71.0
 10          73.0
-15          75.0
 4           77.0
 ....... etc, etc....
```

I would like to bin with respect to the column/variable "variable", so that the same number of rows "X" (say 100) appear in each "variable" bin.

I would then like to scatter plot the central value of each variable bin ((variable_bin_min + variable_bin_max)/2) against the mean of the test scores for that variable bin.

I cannot see a simple way to do this and would be grateful for any guidance!

Comment: I'm confused by the question.  In order to 'bin', you need a variable or column in which to sort (maybe several).  Do you want to 'bin' with respect to your column "variable"?  Can you be certain the data will cooperate with binning into equal number of rows or are you open to that being flexible?  Do you want to calculate the bin_min and bin_max as the min and max of the column "test_score" or "variable"?

Comment: Hi piRSquared! Apologies for any confusion... I am indeed looking to bin with respect to the variable/column "variable". The bins will have irregular size to ensure there are equal numbers of rows in each bin (I am flexible at the edges). The bin_min and bin_max values are the edges of each "variable" bin

Comment: I'm sure the plotting is simple once the initial binning is performed...

Comment: I have edited the initial question to mitigate any confusion

Answer (score 1):

This should get it done.  I manufactured the data, so it won't look like yours.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(variable=np.random.choice(range(20), (1000,)),
                       test_score=np.random.rand(1000,).round(2) * 100))

df_ = df.groupby(pd.qcut(df.variable, len(df) / 100)).agg([np.min, np.max, np.mean])

pd.concat([df_.variable.apply(lambda x: x.loc[['amin', 'amax']].mean(), axis=1),
           df_.test_score['mean']],
          axis=1,
          keys=['bin_center', 'mean_score']).plot.scatter('bin_center', 'mean_score')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do this! That'll work :)

Answer (score 1):

For your bins containing 5 items then pd.cut() to further slice the data :

```
LL     = df['test_score'].tolist()
bins   = LL[::5]
```